# Keeping preferred value of a column and removing the less preferred one

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

The data-frame, df:

```
ID status  year
1    0     2000
1    1     2000
2    0     2001
3    1     2002
3    0     2002
4    1     2002
```

I want to drop '0' status when '1' status is available for the same ID under the same year, such that:

```
ID status  year
1    1     2000
2    0     2001
3    1     2002
4    1     2002
```

I have used following code:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['year', 'id'], keep="first")
```

But the above code drops out some nonzero rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please mask

1. Non duplicated year
   and
2. status=1

Code below

```
df[(~df.duplicated(subset=['year'], keep=False))|(df['status'].eq(1))]



    ID  status  year
1   1       1  2000
2   2       0  2001
3   3       1  2002
5   4       1  2002
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `transform` with `max`

```
m = df.status.eq(df.groupby('ID').status.transform('max'))
df = df[m]
df
   ID  status  year
1   1       1  2000
2   2       0  2001
3   3       1  2002
5   4       1  2002
```